# Regarding shift operator

Tags: java, operators

I have the following snippet but I am not sure if it is correct. Calling the function getdata() should perform some left shift operations. Could you please help me to solve this snippet: what values are going to be returned?

```
 private static String getdata() {
        int i = 0;
        for (int b= 0; b < 16; b++) {
              i |= b<<b
              return Integer.toString(i);
         }
 }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `C`?

Comment: thanks for reply.. I have trying this code with java

Comment: Can't you run it and see what it returns?

Comment: @ Khelwood- why i cant run it could you plz elloborate?

Comment: @ Ghanshyam Mule - Can you please mark the answer correct if you find this correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SOP to print the output on console like the code snippet below.

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        getdata();

    }

    private static void getdata() {
        int i = 0;
        for (int b= 0; b < 16; b++) {
              i |= b<<b;

              System.out.println(i+"\n");
         }
  }
```

OutPut is

506

1018

3066

7162

15354

31738

64506

130042

261114

523258

Comment: thanks Manoj.. for your input.. correct answer!! now  verfied with my answer

Comment: Ghanshyam Mule - can you please mark the answer correct.